# How to use the getAllData() function?

Tags: atk4

After I added a form and loaded some data,

```
$f=$this->add('MVCForm');
$f->setModel('Model')->loadData(1);
$data=$f->getAllData();
```

the data do show up in the fields of the form, however, the $data is empty. I thought it would be the data array for the fields show up in the form. Did I miss something here?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know the reason behind the design or functional behavior of this,
but you need to call the form's `loadData()` first.

Modifying the code you provided:

```
 $f=$this->add('MVCForm');
 $m=$f->setModel('Employee')->loadData(1);
 $f->loadData(); // add this call
 $d=$f->getAllData();

 $b=$this->add('Button')->set('Show Me The Data');
 $b->js('click')->univ()->alert(var_export($d,true));
```

so you can retrieve the data loaded by the model.

i am guessing that this function prepares the form's fields prior to a call to `getAllData()`

or maybe there is a shorter way, ATK has TONS of hidden secrets. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use that inside isSubmitted() function. isSubmitted will automatically call the loadData(). Here is typical use:

```
$form=$this->add('Form');
$form->addField('line','test');
$form->set('test','default value');
$form->addSubmit('Show me the data');

if($form->isSubmitted()){
    $data = $form->getAllData();
    $form->js()->alert(var_export($d,true))->execute();
    // execute at the end is important!
    // it will also stop execution.
}

$this->add('OtherElements'); // other stuff on the page, 
         // which we don't need for form submission logic
```

Comment: But I might need to change the loaded data before I submit the form.  Then the getAllData() inside the isSubmitted() function will retrieve the modified data rather than the ones initially loaded.

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve values you have just set?  Try `$data=$form->getController()->getModel()->get();`

Comment: @CoolMoon, i am thinking that this is what you want:
first is to use MVCForm class, set Model, load record from Model;
next is to change some field's values *BEFORE* rendering;
example would be REMAPPING numbers to strings (1=January, 2=February, etc..)
am i correct or not? or maybe you need to change your question to be more specific..

Comment: I just want to know if there is any easier way to save the data that initially loaded in the form into $DataBefore (right now I am using an additional add('Model')->dsql() to load the data from the database). Then after I made some changes in some fields, the code inside the $f->isSbumitted() will put the new data to $DataAfter, so that I can compare $DataBefore with $DataAfter to see the changes.

Comment: Have you tried `$model->set('field','value')` after setModel() ?